# How to plot a bar plot of mean value by category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a pandas DataFrame with one column labeled `'ocean_proximity'` containing values like `'near ocean'` and `'inland'` and another column labeled `'median_house_value'` with numeric values

I am trying to explore the relationship between these values.

I'm looking to create a bar graph where the x axis is the unique `'ocean_proximity'` string values, and the bar heights being the mean of the related `'median_house_values'`. how can I do this in pandas?

(I have this all running in a `jupyter notebook`, and I've visualizations working generally.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using [`housing.csv`](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/datasets/housing/housing.csv)
- Using [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

  - *Seaborn is a Python data visualization library based on `matplotlib`. It provides a high-level API for drawing attractive and informative statistical graphics.*
  - `seaborn` will automatically aggregate the data for each unique `ocean_proximity`.
  - By default, the `estimator` parameter is `mean`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# lead the data
df = pd.read_csv('data/so_data/2020-08-11 63365958/housing.csv')

# show the mean for each unique value of ocean_proximity. Only show for confirmation of values.
df.groupby('ocean_proximity', as_index=False)['median_house_value'].mean()

[out]:
  ocean_proximity  median_house_value
0       <1H OCEAN       240084.285464
1          INLAND       124805.392001
2          ISLAND       380440.000000
3        NEAR BAY       259212.311790
4      NEAR OCEAN       249433.977427

# plot
p = sns.barplot('ocean_proximity', 'median_house_value', data=df, ci=False)
```

- Note the bar heights are a match to the groupby mean

[image]

- As suggested by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) in the comments

```py
df.groupby('ocean_proximity')['median_house_value'].mean().plot.bar()
```

- Note the bar heights are the same as the previous plot

[image]

### 200 rows of `housing.csv`

```py
longitude,latitude,housing_median_age,total_rooms,total_bedrooms,population,households,median_income,median_house_value,ocean_proximity
-122.23,37.88,41.0,880.0,129.0,322.0,126.0,8.3252,452600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.86,21.0,7099.0,1106.0,2401.0,1138.0,8.3014,358500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.85,52.0,1467.0,190.0,496.0,177.0,7.2574,352100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.85,52.0,1274.0,235.0,558.0,219.0,5.6431,341300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.85,52.0,1627.0,280.0,565.0,259.0,3.8462,342200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.85,52.0,919.0,213.0,413.0,193.0,4.0368,269700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.84,52.0,2535.0,489.0,1094.0,514.0,3.6591,299200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.84,52.0,3104.0,687.0,1157.0,647.0,3.12,241400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.84,42.0,2555.0,665.0,1206.0,595.0,2.0804,226700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.84,52.0,3549.0,707.0,1551.0,714.0,3.6912,261100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.85,52.0,2202.0,434.0,910.0,402.0,3.2031,281500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.85,52.0,3503.0,752.0,1504.0,734.0,3.2705,241800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.85,52.0,2491.0,474.0,1098.0,468.0,3.075,213500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.84,52.0,696.0,191.0,345.0,174.0,2.6736,191300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.85,52.0,2643.0,626.0,1212.0,620.0,1.9167,159200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.85,50.0,1120.0,283.0,697.0,264.0,2.125,140000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.85,52.0,1966.0,347.0,793.0,331.0,2.775,152500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.85,52.0,1228.0,293.0,648.0,303.0,2.1202,155500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.84,50.0,2239.0,455.0,990.0,419.0,1.9911,158700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.84,52.0,1503.0,298.0,690.0,275.0,2.6033,162900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.85,40.0,751.0,184.0,409.0,166.0,1.3578,147500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.85,42.0,1639.0,367.0,929.0,366.0,1.7135,159800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.84,52.0,2436.0,541.0,1015.0,478.0,1.725,113900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.84,52.0,1688.0,337.0,853.0,325.0,2.1806,99700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.84,52.0,2224.0,437.0,1006.0,422.0,2.6,132600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.85,41.0,535.0,123.0,317.0,119.0,2.4038,107500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.85,49.0,1130.0,244.0,607.0,239.0,2.4597,93800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.85,52.0,1898.0,421.0,1102.0,397.0,1.808,105500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.84,50.0,2082.0,492.0,1131.0,473.0,1.6424,108900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.84,52.0,729.0,160.0,395.0,155.0,1.6875,132000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.84,49.0,1916.0,447.0,863.0,378.0,1.9274,122300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.84,52.0,2153.0,481.0,1168.0,441.0,1.9615,115200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.84,48.0,1922.0,409.0,1026.0,335.0,1.7969,110400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.83,49.0,1655.0,366.0,754.0,329.0,1.375,104900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.83,51.0,2665.0,574.0,1258.0,536.0,2.7303,109700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.83,49.0,1215.0,282.0,570.0,264.0,1.4861,97200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.83,48.0,1798.0,432.0,987.0,374.0,1.0972,104500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.83,52.0,1511.0,390.0,901.0,403.0,1.4103,103900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.83,52.0,1470.0,330.0,689.0,309.0,3.48,191400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.83,52.0,2432.0,715.0,1377.0,696.0,2.5898,176000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.83,52.0,1665.0,419.0,946.0,395.0,2.0978,155400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.83,51.0,936.0,311.0,517.0,249.0,1.2852,150000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.84,49.0,713.0,202.0,462.0,189.0,1.025,118800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.84,52.0,950.0,202.0,467.0,198.0,3.9643,188800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.83,52.0,1443.0,311.0,660.0,292.0,3.0125,184400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.83,52.0,1656.0,420.0,718.0,382.0,2.6768,182300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.83,50.0,1125.0,322.0,616.0,304.0,2.026,142500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.82,43.0,1007.0,312.0,558.0,253.0,1.7348,137500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.82,40.0,624.0,195.0,423.0,160.0,0.9506,187500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.82,40.0,946.0,375.0,700.0,352.0,1.775,112500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.82,21.0,896.0,453.0,735.0,438.0,0.9218,171900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.82,43.0,1868.0,456.0,1061.0,407.0,1.5045,93800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.82,41.0,3221.0,853.0,1959.0,720.0,1.1108,97500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.82,52.0,1630.0,456.0,1162.0,400.0,1.2475,104200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.82,52.0,1170.0,235.0,701.0,233.0,1.6098,87500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.82,52.0,945.0,243.0,576.0,220.0,1.4113,83100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.82,52.0,1238.0,288.0,622.0,259.0,1.5057,87500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.82,52.0,1489.0,335.0,728.0,244.0,0.8172,85300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.82,52.0,1387.0,341.0,1074.0,304.0,1.2171,80300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.82,2.0,158.0,43.0,94.0,57.0,2.5625,60000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.83,52.0,1121.0,211.0,554.0,187.0,3.3929,75700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.82,49.0,135.0,29.0,86.0,23.0,6.1183,75000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,50.0,760.0,190.0,377.0,122.0,0.9011,86100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.3,37.81,52.0,1224.0,237.0,521.0,159.0,1.1909999999999998,76100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.3,37.81,48.0,828.0,182.0,392.0,133.0,2.5938,73500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.3,37.81,52.0,1010.0,209.0,604.0,187.0,1.1667,78400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.3,37.81,48.0,1455.0,354.0,788.0,332.0,0.8056,84400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.8,52.0,1027.0,244.0,492.0,147.0,2.6094,81300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.3,37.81,52.0,572.0,109.0,274.0,82.0,1.8516,85000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,46.0,2801.0,644.0,1823.0,611.0,0.9802,129200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,26.0,768.0,152.0,392.0,127.0,1.7719,82500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,46.0,935.0,297.0,582.0,277.0,0.7286,95200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,49.0,844.0,204.0,560.0,152.0,1.75,75000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,46.0,12.0,4.0,18.0,7.0,0.4999,67500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,20.0,835.0,161.0,290.0,133.0,2.483,137500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,17.0,1237.0,462.0,762.0,439.0,0.9241,177500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,36.0,2914.0,562.0,1236.0,509.0,2.4464,102100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,19.0,1207.0,243.0,721.0,207.0,1.1111,108300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.29,37.81,23.0,1745.0,374.0,1054.0,325.0,0.8026,112500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.8,38.0,684.0,176.0,344.0,155.0,2.0114,131300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,17.0,924.0,289.0,609.0,289.0,1.5,162500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.81,52.0,210.0,56.0,183.0,56.0,1.1667,112500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,52.0,340.0,97.0,200.0,87.0,1.5208,112500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,52.0,386.0,164.0,346.0,155.0,0.8075,137500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,35.0,948.0,184.0,467.0,169.0,1.8088,118800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.81,52.0,773.0,143.0,377.0,115.0,2.4083,98200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.81,40.0,880.0,451.0,582.0,380.0,0.977,118800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.81,10.0,875.0,348.0,546.0,330.0,0.76,162500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.8,10.0,105.0,42.0,125.0,39.0,0.9722,137500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.8,52.0,249.0,78.0,396.0,85.0,1.2434,500001.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.8,16.0,994.0,392.0,800.0,362.0,2.0938,162500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.8,52.0,215.0,87.0,904.0,88.0,0.8668,137500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.28,37.8,52.0,96.0,31.0,191.0,34.0,0.75,162500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.79,27.0,1055.0,347.0,718.0,302.0,2.6354,187500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.27,37.8,39.0,1715.0,623.0,1327.0,467.0,1.8477,179200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.8,36.0,5329.0,2477.0,3469.0,2323.0,2.0096,130000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.82,31.0,4596.0,1331.0,2048.0,1180.0,2.8345,183800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.81,29.0,335.0,107.0,202.0,91.0,2.0062,125000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.82,22.0,3682.0,1270.0,2024.0,1250.0,1.2185,170000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.82,37.0,3633.0,1085.0,1838.0,980.0,2.6104,193100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.81,29.0,4656.0,1414.0,2304.0,1250.0,2.4912,257800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.81,28.0,5806.0,1603.0,2563.0,1497.0,3.2177,273400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.81,39.0,854.0,242.0,389.0,228.0,3.125,237500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.81,52.0,2155.0,701.0,895.0,613.0,2.5795,350000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.81,34.0,5871.0,1914.0,2689.0,1789.0,2.8406,335700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.82,52.0,1509.0,225.0,674.0,244.0,4.9306,313400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.81,52.0,2026.0,482.0,709.0,456.0,3.2727,268500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.81,52.0,1758.0,460.0,686.0,422.0,3.1691,259400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.82,52.0,3481.0,751.0,1444.0,718.0,3.9,275700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.82,28.0,3337.0,855.0,1520.0,802.0,3.9063,225000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.82,52.0,1424.0,289.0,550.0,253.0,5.0917,262500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.82,32.0,3809.0,1098.0,1806.0,1022.0,2.6429,218500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.82,26.0,3959.0,1196.0,1749.0,1217.0,3.0233,255000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.83,52.0,2376.0,559.0,939.0,519.0,3.1484,224100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.83,35.0,1613.0,428.0,675.0,422.0,3.4722,243100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.83,52.0,1279.0,287.0,534.0,291.0,3.1429,231600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.83,28.0,5022.0,1750.0,2558.0,1661.0,2.4234,218500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.83,52.0,4190.0,1105.0,1786.0,1037.0,3.0897,234100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.84,50.0,2515.0,399.0,970.0,373.0,5.8596,327600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.84,47.0,3175.0,454.0,1098.0,485.0,5.2868,347600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.83,41.0,2576.0,406.0,794.0,376.0,5.956,366100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.85,37.0,334.0,54.0,98.0,47.0,4.9643,335000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.85,52.0,2800.0,411.0,1061.0,403.0,6.3434,373600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.84,52.0,3529.0,574.0,1177.0,555.0,5.1773,389500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.85,52.0,2612.0,365.0,901.0,367.0,7.2354,391100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.85,28.0,5287.0,1048.0,2031.0,956.0,5.457000000000001,337300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.84,50.0,2935.0,473.0,1031.0,479.0,7.5,295200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.84,44.0,3424.0,597.0,1358.0,597.0,6.0194,292300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.83,40.0,4991.0,674.0,1616.0,654.0,7.5544,411500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.2,37.84,30.0,2211.0,346.0,844.0,343.0,6.0666,311500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.84,34.0,3038.0,490.0,1140.0,496.0,7.0548,325900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.19,37.84,18.0,1617.0,210.0,533.0,194.0,11.6017,392600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.2,37.84,35.0,2865.0,460.0,1072.0,443.0,7.4882,319300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.83,34.0,5065.0,788.0,1627.0,766.0,6.8976,333300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.19,37.83,28.0,1326.0,184.0,463.0,190.0,8.2049,335200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.2,37.83,26.0,1589.0,223.0,542.0,211.0,8.401,351200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.19,37.83,29.0,1791.0,271.0,661.0,269.0,6.8538,368900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.19,37.82,32.0,1835.0,264.0,635.0,263.0,8.317,365900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.2,37.82,37.0,1229.0,181.0,420.0,176.0,7.0175,366700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.2,37.82,39.0,3770.0,534.0,1265.0,500.0,6.3302,362800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.18,37.81,30.0,292.0,38.0,126.0,52.0,6.3624,483300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.82,52.0,2375.0,333.0,813.0,350.0,7.0549,331400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.2,37.81,45.0,2964.0,436.0,1067.0,426.0,6.7851,323500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.8,50.0,2833.0,605.0,1260.0,552.0,2.8929,216700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.8,38.0,2254.0,535.0,951.0,487.0,3.0812,233100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.21,37.81,52.0,1389.0,212.0,510.0,224.0,5.2402,296400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.81,52.0,1971.0,335.0,765.0,308.0,6.5217,273700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.8,52.0,2183.0,465.0,1129.0,460.0,3.2632,227700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.8,52.0,2286.0,464.0,1073.0,441.0,3.0298,199600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.8,52.0,2721.0,541.0,1185.0,515.0,4.5428,239800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.81,52.0,2024.0,339.0,756.0,340.0,4.072,270100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.81,52.0,2944.0,536.0,1034.0,521.0,5.3509,302100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.8,52.0,2033.0,486.0,787.0,459.0,3.1603,269500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.81,52.0,1433.0,229.0,612.0,213.0,4.7708,314700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.81,52.0,2927.0,402.0,1021.0,380.0,8.1564,390100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.81,52.0,2315.0,292.0,861.0,258.0,8.8793,410300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.81,52.0,2485.0,313.0,953.0,327.0,6.8591,352400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.81,52.0,1490.0,238.0,634.0,256.0,6.0302,287300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.81,52.0,2814.0,365.0,878.0,352.0,7.507999999999999,348700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.81,52.0,2093.0,550.0,918.0,483.0,2.7477,243800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.8,52.0,888.0,168.0,360.0,175.0,2.1944,211500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.8,52.0,2087.0,510.0,1197.0,488.0,3.0149,218400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.81,52.0,2513.0,502.0,1048.0,518.0,3.675,269900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.81,46.0,3232.0,835.0,1373.0,747.0,3.225,218800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.8,42.0,4120.0,1065.0,1715.0,1015.0,2.9345,225000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.8,43.0,2364.0,792.0,1359.0,722.0,2.1429,250000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.8,41.0,1471.0,469.0,1062.0,413.0,1.6121,171400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.8,29.0,2468.0,864.0,1335.0,773.0,1.3929,193800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.79,27.0,1632.0,492.0,1171.0,429.0,2.3173,125000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.79,45.0,1786.0,526.0,1475.0,460.0,1.7772,97500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.79,50.0,629.0,188.0,742.0,196.0,2.6458,125000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.79,52.0,1339.0,391.0,1086.0,363.0,2.181,138800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.8,36.0,1678.0,606.0,1645.0,543.0,2.2303,116700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.8,43.0,2344.0,647.0,1710.0,644.0,1.6504,151800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.8,52.0,996.0,228.0,731.0,228.0,2.2697,127000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.8,52.0,1591.0,373.0,1118.0,347.0,2.1563,128600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.8,52.0,1586.0,398.0,1006.0,335.0,2.1348,140600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.8,47.0,2046.0,588.0,1213.0,554.0,2.6292,182700.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.8,52.0,1192.0,289.0,772.0,257.0,2.3833,146900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.8,52.0,1803.0,420.0,1321.0,401.0,2.957,122800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.8,49.0,2838.0,749.0,1487.0,677.0,2.5238,169300.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.8,52.0,783.0,184.0,488.0,186.0,1.9375,126600.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.8,51.0,1590.0,414.0,949.0,392.0,1.9028,127900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.8,50.0,1746.0,480.0,1149.0,415.0,2.25,123500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.8,52.0,1252.0,299.0,844.0,280.0,2.3929,111900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.79,43.0,5963.0,1344.0,4367.0,1231.0,2.1917,112800.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.79,52.0,1783.0,395.0,1659.0,412.0,2.9357,107900.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.79,30.0,999.0,264.0,1011.0,263.0,1.8854,137500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.79,39.0,1469.0,431.0,1464.0,389.0,2.1638,105500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.79,47.0,1372.0,395.0,1237.0,303.0,2.125,95500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.79,52.0,674.0,180.0,647.0,168.0,3.375,116100.0,NEAR BAY
-122.24,37.79,43.0,1626.0,376.0,1284.0,357.0,2.2542,112200.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.79,51.0,175.0,43.0,228.0,55.0,2.1,75000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.79,39.0,461.0,129.0,381.0,123.0,1.6,112500.0,NEAR BAY
-122.25,37.79,52.0,902.0,237.0,846.0,227.0,3.625,125000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.26,37.8,20.0,2373.0,779.0,1659.0,676.0,1.6929,115000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.77,52.0,391.0,128.0,520.0,138.0,1.6471,95000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.22,37.77,52.0,1137.0,301.0,866.0,259.0,2.59,96400.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.77,52.0,769.0,206.0,612.0,183.0,2.57,72000.0,NEAR BAY
-122.23,37.78,52.0,472.0,146.0,415.0,126.0,2.6429,71300.0,NEAR BAY
```